# Angular *ngFor create table with group item?

Tags: angular

This is my data:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "item 1",
    "group": "Group A"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "item 2",
    "group": "Group A"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "item 3",
    "group": "Group B"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "item 4",
    "group": "Group B"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "item 5",
    "group": "Group B"
}, {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "item 6",
    "group": "Group C"
}]
```

And I want to create table like this:

```
|======================|
|ID     |NAME          |
|======================|
|Group A               |
|----------------------|
|1      |item 1        |
|2      |item 2        |
|======================|
|Group B               |
|----------------------|
|3      |item 3        |
|4      |item 4        |
|5      |item 5        |
|======================|
|Group C               |
|----------------------|
|6      |item 6        |
========================
```

I tried create variable to store "group" in each loop but not work and
I can group at server side before return data, I still want do it at client, so how to do that ?

Comment: What is the output you want in angular?

Comment: i want create table like above

Comment: http://ng-table.com/#/grouping/demo-grouping-basic Check this link\

Comment: Just like shown in above comment you can check plenty of options. If you want it dynamically you can go with Kendo Grid for Angular. Which gives you inbuilt grouping functionality

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use below logic for achieving your result.

```
var groups = new Set(array.map(item => item.group)), 
    results = [];
groups.forEach(g => 
  results.push({
    name: g, 
    values: array.filter(i => i.group === g)
  }
))
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let item in results">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
      <ng-container>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2">{{item.name}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let value in item.values">
          <td>{{value.id}}</td>
          <td>{{value.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
   </table>
<div>
```

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zuizne)

Comment: thanks u, can you help me convert "groups " back to flat array, i can do this by using foreach and push to new array, but i want know your way

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to create your array as group by with group name.

I have created a demo in **[stackblitz](https://group-by-inangular.stackblitz.io/)**. Hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

> .ts file code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  array = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "item 1",
      "group": "Group A"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "item 2",
      "group": "Group A"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "item 3",
      "group": "Group B"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "item 4",
      "group": "Group B"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "item 5",
      "group": "Group B"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "item 6",
      "group": "Group C"
    }
  ];

    groupArr = this.array.reduce((r,{group})=>{
        if(!r.some(o=>o.group==group)){
          r.push({group,groupItem:this.array.filter(v=>v.group==group)});
    }
    return r;
    },[]);

}
```

> template

```
   <table>
     <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
        <tbody *ngFor="let item of groupArr">
             <ng-container>
        <tr >
          <td colspan="2"><b>{{item.group}}</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let value of item.groupItem">
          <td>{{value.id}}</td>
          <td>{{value.name}}</td>
        </tr>
      </ng-container></tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: thanks u, and one more thing can you help me convert "groupArr" back to flat array, i can do this by using foreach, but i want know your way

Comment: for this you can again use `reduce ` and the `spread syntax ` to get flat array again.  Like this  `groupArr.reduce((r,{groupItem})=>[...r,...groupItem],[])`